# Run multiple functions in R

Tags: r

I have multiple functions  without any input. I am interested to be able to run them all at once, but also to preserve the flexibility of running them one by one. For example:

```
wrap_function<-function{

fun1<-function(){}  
fun2<-function(){}  
}
```

How can I run all functions together without unpacking them and calling all functions one by one?

Comment: What do you mean unpacking? Your wrapper merely defines fun1 and fun2 but does not run them btw.

Answer (score 2):

Just define them:

```
fun1<-function(){print("hello")}  
fun2<-function(){print("world")}
```

Define a wrapper if you want:

```
wrap_function <- function() {
fun1()
fun2()
}
```

Then calling `wrap_function()` will run all of them and calling them individually (with `fun1()` or `fun2()`) will call them individually.

```
> wrap_function()
[1] "hello"
[1] "world"

> fun1()
[1] "hello"
```

Note that your wrapper syntax is wrong, see my code.